# nginx not responding on port 81

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I just installed and configured nginx to listen on port 81. I didn't change the `nginx.conf` file, removed `sites-available/default`, added a `dystroy.org` file in `sites-available` :

```
server {
    listen 81;

    root /var/www/dystroy;
    index index.html index.php;

    server_name dystroy.org www.dystroy.org;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

and I linked it :

```
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx$ ls -al sites-available/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 dys dys 4096 Nov 19 11:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 dys dys 4096 Nov 19 10:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dys dys  190 Nov 19 11:01 dystroy.org
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx$ ls -al sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 dys dys 4096 Nov 19 11:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 dys dys 4096 Nov 19 10:31 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dys dys   27 Nov 19 10:35 dystroy.org -> sites-available/dystroy.org
```

The process is running but the server doesn't answer at all, neither remotely nor locally :

```
dystroy@server: curl -i localhost:81
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

There's nothing in `error.log`.

What did I do wrong ? How can I find and fix the error ?

Comment: Did you restart nginx after changing the config? Do you have a firewall blocking connections? What does `netstat -na|grep LISTEN |grep :81` show?

Comment: Yes I restarted and I have no firewall (it's a server with applications already listening on many ports, I tried with a few other ones here). grep doesn't find `:81` in your netstat command output.

Comment: Can you post us the output of `ls -la sites-available/` and `ls -la sites-enabled/`?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine question updated. And yes, you guessed right, my link is wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me guess, this is how you made your symbolic link:

```
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx$ ln -s sites-available/dystroy.org sites-enabled/
```

Well, this creates a wrong symbolic link.

[image]

As you can see in this image with colors enabled, the symbolic link doesn't point to an existing path.

For simplicity, use absolute paths.

```
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx$ ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/dystroy.org /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dystroy.org
```

See my fixed example:

[image]

Then, restart nginx and you should be good to go.

For completeness, this is how you can make a working relative path:

```
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx$ ln -s ../sites-available/dystroy.org sites-enabled/dystroy.org
```

[image]

Or, to have the bash completion while making the link:

```
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx$ cd sites-enabled/
dystroy@server:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ln -s ../sites-available/dystroy.org .
```

[image]